# WCF: Deal with SSPI exception without set a dummy identity

Tags: c#, wcf

I have the problem that changing the identity under which the WCF service runs on the server side affects my client authentication. I use the default security settings on client and server, so I think the security mode is transport. And after changing the domainuser which runs my wcf service it looks like the client needs another binding configuration. I got the following exception when I tried to call the service:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The target principal name is incorrect

BTW: I know that adding an identity tag on the client will solve my problem. But I am not able to do this. I have no access to all clients.

Does anybody have an idea? How is it possible to change the service user without affecting the clients.